# OpenGL transperency is opaque

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I know this has been asked before, but none of the other answers helps with my specific problem. I have a simple C++ and OpenGL program where I'm drawing a textured cube. The transparency of the texture show up as black. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "shader.h"
#include "mesh.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "OpenGL Test", sf::Style::Close);
sf::Event event;

glewInit();

//clear color
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glAlphaFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//view and projection matrix
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective<float>(glm::radians(45.f), 640.f / 480.f, 0.1f, 100.f); //fov, ratio, display range min, display range max

glm::mat4  view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(4, 3, 3), //camera position
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), //camera looking at this position
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0) //head is up
    );

//shader
Shader shader;

shader.loadVertex("testShader.vs");
shader.loadFragment("testShader.fs");
shader.link();

float points[] = {

    -0.8, -0.8, -0.8,
    -0.8, 0.8, -0.8,
    0.8, 0.8, -0.8,
    0.8, -0.8, -0.8,

    -0.8, 0.8, 0.8,
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8,

    -0.8, -0.8, 0.8,
    0.8, -0.8, 0.8
};

//irrelevent for now...
float colors[] = {
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1
};

float texCoords[] = {
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0
};

unsigned int elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, //front
    1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1, //top
    4, 6, 7, 7, 5, 4, //back
    6, 0, 3, 3, 7, 6, //bottom
    3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 3, //right
    6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 6 //left
};


Mesh mesh(&projection, &view, 8, points, 36, elements, texCoords, colors);
mesh.setShader(shader);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        //resize viewport if window is resized
        else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mesh.draw();

    window.display();
}


return 0;
}
```

I'm not going to post all of my code because it's in separate classes, but here's the code for loading the texture in case it's important.

```
//texture
sf::Image image;
image.loadFromFile("Numel.png");

textureID = 0;

glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, false, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

And here are my shaders:

(Vertex shader)

```
#version 450

in vec3 v_pos;
in vec3 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoord;

out vec3 color;
out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    color=v_color;
    texCoord=v_texCoord;
    gl_Position=mvp*vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
}
```

(Fragment Shader)

```
#version 450

in vec3 color;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 f_color;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    f_color=texture2D(texture, texCoord);
}
```

And just to clarify, my image is a PNG, it is 256x256 (power of 2 size), and it does in fact have transparent pixels.

Comment: This is a valid programming question. Please do not vote to close it.

Comment: Debugging tip: Run your program through gDEBugger or CodeXL to see if the internal data is correct or not after loading the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the blend function. You may *think* you do with the following call:

```
glAlphaFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But that's something different. This call would be used to set the alpha test function. If you don't know what that is... don't bother. Alpha test is a deprecated piece of functionality that is not supported anymore in the OpenGL core profile. There were actually some cases where it was very useful in fixed function OpenGL, but those can easily be implemented with the programmable pipeline, so the dedicated alpha test is not really needed anymore.

What you wanted to call to set the blend function is:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Make sure that you **always** call `glGetError()` if your OpenGL code does not work as expected. In this case, you would have gotten an error immediately, because `glAlphaFunc()` takes very different arguments than `glBlendFunc()`, so `glGetError()` would have returned `GL_INVALID_ENUM` immediately.

Comment: ...or better yet, use a debugger (gDEBugger or CodeXL)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I was using glAlphaFunc() instead of glBlendFunc(). It works now!